# spacing chapter documentclass report

Tags: spacing

I think this question has been discussed here but I still haven't found a solution. I am using document class report and there is one thing I am not able to figure out. I have still spacing for Chapters, Bibliography, Nomenclatures although I have set top spacing to 0 and titlespacing values are set to 0 as well. You can modify values in titlespacing and use a negative value but it doesn't seem to be correct for me. I don't know how but it worked well for some time but I did some modification to my document and I ended up with the same problem.
I would like to have my spacing to look like in the first picture.
[image]

But I still have this (see second picture)
[image]

Could anyone help me out please? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please add a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) to the question that lets us reproduce your output.

Comment: What is the black line on the top of your pictures ? If it is the top of the page, then it is a margin (here the size of the header) problem rather than a spacing problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for your respond. The problem was caused by the size of the header as mvienney mentioned. 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.